How to use Splide ttb slider without fixed height
I have a vertical slider Splide. There is text inside each slide. The text may be different, so the fixed parameter "height": "5rem" is not suitable for me, but without it there is an error in the console. How can I solve this problem?


<div class="announcement-bar__slider splide" data-splide='{"drag": false, "type":"loop", "arrows": false, "pagination": false, "speed": 600, "direction": "ttb", "height": "5rem", "perPage": 1, "perMove": 1, "autoplay": true, "interval": 3500}'>



